# get html version from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

For example, I have this URL: `www.pawgoes.nl`. If I look to the page source, then I can see that this website has version `XHTML 1.0 Transitional`.

My question is, is there a library or standard functionality in .NET that gives me the html version programmatically of a given URL? Because I have a huge list of URLS and I need to know the HTMl version of all of them

Thanks in advance

Comment: That document may have an XHTML 1.0 Transitional Doctype, but it is invalid. There is little practical value to be had in knowing what Doctype is being used (unless you are trying to edit that particular document).

Answer (score 1):

With the code sample below you will get the doctype, from that you can extract the version.

```
HtmlWeb webGet = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = webGet.Load("http://www.pawgoes.nl/");
string doctype = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//comment()").InnerText;
```

Comment: Can you give some advice how I extract the version out of the doctype? Is there any pattern in the doctype so I can do a `substring`or something. The doctype for `http://www.pawgoes.nl/` is `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">`

Comment: You can try to find "html" with an indexof and from their extract the version number, the only exception is the html5 doctype.

Answer (score 0):

No, but this is trivial to implement yourself.

Use [WebClient.DownloadString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) and probably the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).